# Tem como definir no composer o sistema operacional requerido?

Tags: composer

Construí um pacote PHP para implantação via composer, porém, este só funciona em máquinas Windows. No composer.json é possível especificar essa restrição?

Comment: Acredito que não seja possível, até onde sei o composer é usado para gerenciamento de pacotes não para definir qual OS é requerido, mesmo assim vou procurar sobre.

Comment: Não é possível determinar tal requisito no composer, dado que o composer é um gerenciador de dependências, o máximo seria especificar uma versão do PHP e suas extensões.

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisando não encontrei nada que limitasse a instalação em máquinas com *SO's* incompatíveis. Porém me é estranho um pacote que sirva apenas em um *SO* já que o `PHP` é uma linguagem interpretada e não compilada.

Mas eu acredito que seja impossível fazer tal limitação, uma vez que o *Composer* serve para gerenciar as dependências, acredito que o máximo que você consiga fazer é definir uma versão para o `PHP`, já que o *Composer* é um gerenciador de pacotes `PHP`.

Comment: Meu pacote faz uso da biblioteca dotnet para conexão COM. Diante disso apresenta incompatibilidade em sistemas que não sejam windows. Veja: https://packagist.org/packages/crphp/wmi

Comment: Entendi, mas infelizmente não é possível definir a obrigatoriedade do Windows com o composer.:/